# Codeigniter get list of names from table1 that have id from table2

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a need to grab a list of names and their ID from 'users' table that have a 'groupid' of the groups I am displaying. I am using CodeIgniter

In my view I want to accomplish a table with the following:

```
| GroupID  | Group Name          | Users in Group         |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 10001    | Group1              | User1, User3, User5    |
| 10002    | Group2              | User2, User6           |
| 10003    | Group3              | User4                  |
```

So basically each groupid entry in the table I would like to have a list of users that are in that group under the column "Users in Group", comma separated.
Each User in the "Users in Group" column being a link to their "Edit User" page, which is a page that has the URL mysite.com/admin/edituser/USERID

My controller:

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database('admin');
    $this->load->model('adminmodel','',TRUE);
 }
 public function groups() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('loggedin')) {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('loggedin');
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('sidebar');
        $data['group_results'] = $this->adminmodel->list_groups();
        foreach ($data['group_results'] as $group_results) {
            $data['name_results'][$group_results['id']] = $this->adminmodel->list_users_in_group($group_results['id']);
        }
        $this->load->view('admin/groups', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer-nocharts');
    }
    else {
        //If no session, redirect to login page
        redirect('user/login', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

My model:

```
function list_groups() {
    $this->db->select('id, name');
    $this->db->from('groups')->order_by('id','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function list_users_in_group($groupid) {
    $this->db->select('users.name, users.id, groups.id');
    $this->db->from('users')->order_by('users.name','asc');
    $this->db->where('groups.id', $groupid);
    $this->db->join('groups', 'groups.id = users.groupid');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

And the view:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 38px;">GroupID</th>
            <th style="width: 150px;">Group Name</th>
            <th style="width: 40px;">Users Assigned</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($admin_results as $admin_entry): ?>
            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td><?php echo $admin_entry->id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $admin_entry->name; ?></td>
                <td>
                <?php foreach ($name_results as $name): ?>
                    <?php echo "<a href='/admin/edituser/".$id."'>".$name."</a>,&nbsp;"; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The database is pretty simple, two tables, two columns each.
Users table has columns 'id' (primary key), 'name'
Groups table has columns 'groupid' (primary key), 'name'

With the setup I have above in my code, I return error:
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /var/www/html/application/controllers/admin.php on line 36 and I don't seem to understand why.

Thank you for help.

--------------- EDIT ------
After reading a comment and an answer I changed a few things accordingly.

Model:

```
function list_groups() {
    $this->db->select('id, name');
    $this->db->from('groups')->order_by('id','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}

function list_users_in_group($groupid) {
    $this->db->select('users.name, users.id, groups.id');
    $this->db->from('users')->order_by('users.name','asc');
    $this->db->where('groups.id', $groupid);
    $this->db->join('groups', 'groups.id = users.groupid');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

( basically made list_groups return an array )

Now, on my view in that column I receive errors:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: id
Filename: admin/groups.php
Line Number: 31

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 4096
Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string
Filename: admin/groups.php
Line Number: 31

Thanks again.

Comment: If you want an array - try with: return $query->result_array() in list_groups() function in model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it figured out.

My main trouble was that as I was not assigning a key to my $data['name_results'] array, it was displaying all of them or only the first two. Assigning a key made it all better.

The controller:

```
public function groups() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('loggedin')) {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('loggedin');
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('sidebar');
        $data['group_results'] = $this->adminmodel->list_groups();
        foreach ($data['group_results'] as $group_results) {
            $data['name_results'][$group_results['id']] = $this->adminmodel->list_users_in_group($group_results['id']);
        }
        $this->load->view('admin/groups', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer-nocharts');
    }
    else {
        //If no session, redirect to login page
        redirect('user/login', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

The model:

```
function list_groups() {
    $this->db->select('id, name');
    $this->db->from('groups')->order_by('id','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}

function list_users_in_group($groupid) {
    $this->db->select('users.username, users.id, users.groupid');
    $this->db->from('users')->order_by('users.username','asc');
    $this->db->where('users.groupid', $groupid);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

The view:

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($group_results as $group_entry): ?>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <td><?php echo $group_entry['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $group_entry['name']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php foreach ($name_results[$group_entry['id']] as $name): ?>
                    <?php echo "<a href='/admin/edituser/".$name['id']."'>".$name['username']."</a>,&nbsp;"; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Functions correctly. Thank you both for your assistance in getting a few things I overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your code samples, but it seems that this line

```
$data['group_results'] = $this->adminmodel->list_groups();
```

returns an instance of [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php). However, on the next line, you want to `foreach` on that instance, which is not possible for this particular class.

To remedy this problem, you can simply typecast that `stdClass` instance into a normal array, like this:

```
$data['group_results'] = (array)$this->adminmodel->list_groups();
```

This way, you are telling PHP to convert that instance into an array upon assignment and then you can do a `foreach` on it.

If you are in control of `adminmodel->list_groups()` implementation, you may as well refactor it so that it returns an array instead of `stdClass`. I will leave that to you to figure out how to do so in CodeIgniter.